# Lottery on wordpress using php and json

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am currently building a website for my guild (on a video game).
The video game (Guild wars 2) provide us a feed of everything being done inside the guild in a json file (user joining, withdraw of money, deposit of items, kick, etc...).
Since I have this feed, auto-updated, I would like to setup a lottery, working on the following :
- guild member (user) buy a ticket => deposit golds in our bank (displayed as deposit)
- display this information on the website => user "x" has bought a ticket at H:M:DD:MM:Y (for example)
- at the end of the month, script to random a winner from this list of users (this random must include only tickets bought between date A & B)

I have managed to write a little code, and it is working, only to display a list of users and their actions :

```
<?php

$apikey = '(My API key)';
$guildkey = '(My guild key)';

$jsontest =file_get_contents ('https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/guild/'.$guildkey.'/log?access_token='. $apikey);

$json = json_decode($jsontest,true);

foreach($json as $member)
{
   if ($member['coins'] > 1)
      print "Guild member "."".$member['user'].""." has bought a ticket for ".$member['coins']." golds"." ";
}
?>
```

Here a little example of how the guild wars 2 api output is :

> {
>       "type": "upgrade",
>       "item_id": 77729,
>       "count": 1,
>       "action": "completed",
>       "id": 896815,
>       "time": "2017-02-23T14:26:29.000Z",
>       "user": "Lehi.5091",
>       "upgrade_id": 668
>     },
>     {
>       "id": 896814,
>       "time": "2017-02-23T14:26:29.000Z",
>       "type": "upgrade",
>       "upgrade_id": 668,
>       "action": "queued"
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "upgrade",
>       "item_id": 77729,
>       "count": 1,
>       "action": "completed",
>       "id": 896810,
>       "time": "2017-02-23T14:26:28.000Z",
>       "user": "Lehi.5091",
>       "upgrade_id": 668

As intended, it does display what I want, [here the working code](http://dkbguild.eu/test/) 
If you have tips or anything about how to this, I'll gladly take them.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: As written, it's difficult for the general programming community to help out here without having specific knowledge of how Guildwars does it's API. Could you provide an example response from the API access (`var_export($jsontest);`), preferably scrubbed of any sensitive information?

Comment: I did edit the post and added an example of how does a guild wars 2 output api is like, this is the kind of output for guild keys. It has lots of differents for other contents in the game, but for the guild, it's like this one.
Hope this is better, sorry for putting sensitive informations